# How to take multiple Sample() vector outputs and combine them into a data frame

Tags: r

sorry if this is a somewhat basic question. But I am wanting to take a random sample sample of data from each day (coming from separate files), using the sample() function, and then combine each of those sampled rows from the day data and combine it all into a week data frame of only my sampled data from the day datasets.

Comment: have you been able o read the files in separately? Can you include any code/reproducible data or error messages that we can help with? At the moment this question is a little too broad

Comment: My apologies for being vague. I’ll be sure on the future to include more information in my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the data is held in files name for their day, like *mydata_2020_05_17.csv*

```
library(tidyverse)
readDay <- function(date, dir, sampleN){
  path <- paste0(dir, "/", "mydata_", date, ".csv")
  read_csv(path) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
      # You many not need this if the records already have the date
    mutate(DATE = date) %>% 
    sample_n(sampleN, replace = FALSE)
}
```

Lets start on the first Sunday of the month

```
answerWeek = map_df(seq.Date(from = as_date("2020-05-03"), length.out = 6, by = 1),
                    ~ readDay(.x, "~/nefarious/data", sampleN = 20))
```

NOT RUN because I don't have a folder full of dated csv data.
Let us know if I've mis-interpreted what you're looking for.

Comment: Damon, I know you're new here.  It's good form on StackOverflow (SO), when somebody has answered your post in a way that works well, to _accept_ their answer, so that they get reputation points for it.  'Accepting' is done by clicking the gray checkmark (upper left of the post).  It'll turn green.

Comment: My sincerest apologies. Thank you for the help. I’ll keep this in mind for the future.